# why doesn't this program get the conditions right just before partition?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I was writing a program to sort using *Quick-Sort* algorithm. But my program does not get the situation right just before partition.For example if i enter 5 numbers :

```
100  200  30  1  2

// after first quick sort (considering 30 as the pivot element)

2  200  30  1  100 // i get this fine

// after second quick sort

2   1  30  200  100 // but don't get this one
```

After i have entered these numbers i get the output as :

```
pivot encountereed
2 , 30 , 30 , 1 , 100 ,
2 , 30 , 30 , 1 , 100 ,
2 , 30 , 30 , 1 , 100 ,
```

#### **Program**

```
/*
 * @ author Suhail Gupta
 */
```

## include

```
using namespace std;

void quickSort(unsigned int,int,int*,int*);
int *ptrTowardsRight; // pointer that points to the element to its right  ( ---> )
int *ptrTowardsLeft;  // pointer that points to the element to its left  ( <--- )
int *arr;
int size;
bool pivotEncountered = false;

int main()
{

    cout << "Number of elements you want to sort : ";
    cin >> size;

    cout << "Enter the numbers : " << endl;
    arr = new int[size]; // declare the size of array
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ".) ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int left = arr[0];
    int right = arr[size-1];
    unsigned int pivotIndex = (int)size/2;
    int pivotVal = arr[pivotIndex];

    ptrTowardsRight = &arr[0];
    ptrTowardsLeft = &arr[size-1];
    // call the function to start quick sort
    quickSort( pivotIndex , pivotVal , ptrTowardsRight , ptrTowardsLeft);
}

void quickSort(unsigned int pivotIndex , int pivotVal , int *ptrTowardsRight , int *ptrTowardsLeft )
{

    int count_RP = size-1; // count right of pivot , gets the index of backend
    while(*ptrTowardsLeft >= pivotVal)
    {
        if(*ptrTowardsLeft == pivotVal)
        {
            pivotEncountered = true;
            break;
        }
        ptrTowardsLeft--;
        count_RP--;
    }

    int count_LP = 0;// count left of pivot , gets the index of front end
    while(*ptrTowardsRight <= pivotVal)
    {
        if(*ptrTowardsRight == pivotVal)
        {
            pivotEncountered = true;
            break;
        }
        ptrTowardsRight++;
        count_LP++;
    }

    // Now swap the values
    int temp = arr[count_LP];
    arr[count_LP] = *ptrTowardsLeft;
    arr[count_RP] = temp;
    // values swapped

    ptrTowardsRight = &arr[count_LP];
    ptrTowardsLeft = &arr[count_RP];

    if(pivotEncountered)
    {
        // call to partition(...)
        cout << "pivot encountereed";
    }
    else
    {
        quickSort(pivotIndex,pivotVal,ptrTowardsRight,ptrTowardsLeft);  // recursive call to quickSort(...)
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " , ";
    }

}
```

Where does the logic in the program go wrong ? **If i comment the recursive call to the `quickSort(...)` , then the output is , what it should be.** *(2  200  30  1  100)*

Comment: The code is really hard to read as formatted/organized currently.

Comment: why make it so complicated ? A quick review of the code is giving me a feeling that some basic steps are missing

Comment: Step through the code. At each step, inspect the contents of the array and compare it to what you expect to be in the array. At some point, your expectation and reality will diverge. That is where you should focus your investigation.

Comment: @ Raymond Chen @ interjay the problem starts after the recursive call to quick sort. I am unable to detect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine except the last call when `*ptrTowardsLeft` and `*ptrTowardsRight` both are equal to `30`. So in this case also swapping is done. To avoid this :

```
if(pivotEncountered != true) {  // use this condition 
 // Now swap the values
 int temp = arr[count_LP];
 arr[count_LP] = *ptrTowardsLeft;
 arr[count_RP] = temp;
// values swapped
 ptrTowardsRight = &arr[count_LP];  
 ptrTowardsLeft = &arr[count_RP];
}
```

and after this else part won't work and you can carry on your partition.

**output**

```
2 , 1 , 30 , 200 , 100 // after encountering the pivot element
```

*Though this code requires many fixes.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is all wrong:

> ```
> // after first quick sort (considering 30 as the pivot element)
>
> 2  200  30  1  100 // i get this fine
> ```

NOT fine! 200 is more than 30 (the pivot), so it should be to the right of it. 1, OTOH, should be to the left of it (something like `2 1 30 200 100`).

> ```
>  // Now swap the values
>  int temp = arr[count_LP];
>  arr[count_LP] = *ptrTowardsLeft;
>  arr[count_RP] = temp;
> ```

This is not gonna work once you have `ptrTowardsLeft`/`Right` arguments not pointing at the end/beginning of the array. Try to use your pointers only, and don't touch `arr`.

Also, the structure of your algorithm doesn't even resemble to QuickSort. QuickSort swaps the elements so that all values less than the pivot are in the left part and values greater than the pivot are in the right. Then recurse to sort the two parts of the array. You don't do anything like that.

Comment: yeah i know..I recently learned about quick sort. There have been some confusions , some misinterpretations . Now i am much clear. But this code indeed makes an attempt to get the condition for partition and it does if you apply the fix that i have given but for limited cases !